# read from one and write into second excel file - PHP

Tags: php, excel

I have one excel file with a lot of data, this is an example of one row open in the editor:

```
"A","001270","3755","TRIPP LITE MASTER-POWER","UPS EXTERNAL BATTERY PACK TOWER","12/24V APS INVERTER CHARGERS","0000000000000421.20","BP-260","000019.80","0037332080011","0015.00","0014.00","0019.50","","0000000000000222.80","0000000000000000.00","N","","UPS-C","BATT","0101","","N","","00000000000000.0000","2 YEAR LTD",""
```

I have this code that works good with one condition

```
$table = fopen('read.csv','r');
$temp_table = fopen('write','w');
while (($data = fgetcsv($table)) !== FALSE){
    if(in_array($data[1],$spec)){ // this is if you need the first column in a row
        continue;
    }
    fputcsv($temp_table,$data);
}
fclose($table);
fclose($temp_table);
```

And as a result in the new file ive got row like this:

```
A,001270,3755,"TRIPP LITE MASTER-POWER","UPS EXTERNAL BATTERY PACK TOWER","12/24V APS INVERTER CHARGERS",0000000000000421.20,BP-260,000019.80,0037332080011,0015.00,0014.00,0019.50,,0000000000000222.80,0000000000000000.00,N,,UPS-C,BATT,0101,,N,,00000000000000.0000,"2 YEAR LTD",
```

The problem is when i open a new file in the editor, it doesnt have "" in the begining and in the end of values, and that is the problem, what i did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, you just need to put `.csv` at line `$temp_table = fopen('write.csv','w');` because you're using `fputcsv()` function in the while loop. which is generating output based on csv file standards. if you get output in `.txt` format some columns would missing quotes `""`. In that case you need to handle this manually.

**Edit**

if you don't want to output it as csv than replace your code with the below updated code.

```
$table = fopen('read.csv','r');
$temp_table = fopen('write.txt','w');
while (($data = fgetcsv($table)) !== FALSE){
    $data = '"'. implode('","', $data) .'"'; // this line will add the comma and double quote to each array value and wrap the string with double quote.
    fputs($temp_table,$data);
}
fclose($table);
fclose($temp_table);
```

Comment: It's better to post a complete code block, with an explanation. Because it's easier to understand for the reader.

Comment: But I want to save my end file without CSV extension